# Why does using -F flag work while explicitly changing field separator by using FS variable not work when field seperator to be changed is '\t' in awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

While experimenting with the Unix tool **awk**, I came across this subtlety which I couldn't explain. Suppose this is the file I am using as `file.txt`

```
Carl Gauss      1       Germany
Isaac Newton    2       England
Leonhard Euler  3       Switzerland
Donald Knuth    4       America
Alan Turing     5       England
Albert Einstein 6       Germany
```

The columns are separated by a Tab.
Now suppose I want to extract the first field in each row, so here are the two way I tried to approach this:

Test 1:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F'\t' '
{print $1;}
' file.txt
```

The output, as expected is:

```
Carl Gauss
Isaac Newton
Leonhard Euler
Donald Knuth
Alan Turing
Albert Einstein
```

Now I tried another supposedly equivalent way to solve this problem:

Test 2:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
BEGIN {
        FS='\t';
}
{print $1;}
' file.txt
```

The output which I got in this case was

```
C
I
L
D
A
A
```

Only the first letters of the rows are being printed. As far as I know, both the methods should be equivalent but they are producing different outputs. I tried this out on different `file.txt` files created in different ways as well but I got the same result each time.

What is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 17):

1. You can't use `'` within a `'`-delimited string (including a script) in Bourne-like shells such as `bash`.
2. The string delimiter inside an awk script is `"`, not `'`.

Just change `FS='\t'` to `FS="\t"`.

Your current code is breaking out of the awk script after `FS=`, then has a standalone `\t` in the shell script, then re-entering the awk script after it:

```
'BEGIN{     FS='\t              ' }             '
^shell ends    ^awk ends        ^shell ends     ^awk ends
 awk begins     shell begins     awk begins      shell begins
```

That `\t` is entirely being interpreted by your shell BEFORE awk is called and `\t` in an unquoted string in shell is the same as just `t` since `t` is already literal in shell in that context so writing:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS='\t' }'
```

is equivalent to writing:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS='t' }'
```

which is equivalent to writing:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=t }'
```

and in that script awk sees `t` as an uninitialized variable and so that's (for the purpose of field-splitting) equivalent to writing:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="" }'
```

which is undefined behavior (will do different things in different awk variants).

You may get some answers and/or comments advising you to call awk using a shebang instead of just calling it from your shell but don't do that, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001 for why.

Comment: the syntax highlighting reveals the issue nicely, btw.